# Subset shapefile polygons based on values in a separate spreadsheet (.csv)

Tags: r, subset, shapefile

I have a polygon shapefile of sampling strata, which contains in the attributes table the name/ID of each respective polygon (StrataID). In a separate .csv file, I again have the same strata IDs in addition to the sampling effort to be employed in each respective strata.

However, where some strata are not always sampled (sample size of 0), and the GRTS function (spsurvey) for spatial sampling does not allow for zero effort, those strata without effort are removed; I am left with a .csv file which contains only strata with a sampling effort >0. From this subset of strata, I need to sync with the shapefile containing the strata polygons that samples will be allocated to (i.e., strata polygons which will not be sampled have to removed from the shapefile).

Is there a way to subset a shapefile by recalling only those IDs present in a separate spreadsheet?

Both the shapefile (strata) and .csv (effort) employ identical strata identifiers.

I've played around with the subset and other functions with minimal success:

```
# the second column of the strata file is StrataID
strata <- strata[strata@data[,2] %in% c(effort$StrataID)]
```

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Plz provide some dummy data.

Comment: Your going to subset some observation, so there should be a comma: `strata <- strata[strata@data[,2] %in% c(effort$StrataID), ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
countrydf <- data.frame(country = c('Brazil', 'Bolivia', 'Argentina'))
sampl <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl@data[, 5] %in% countrydf$country, ]
```

or

```
sampl <- subset(wrld_simpl, NAME %in% countrydf$country)

plot(sampl, axes = T)
```

[image: plot countries]